# Helpme please query about postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to extract a number of characters from one column to another and insert it into another column

| number_operation | communication | test |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | B003-00000005 |  |
|  | FCI-0023 |  |
|  | 0097 |  |
|  | F004-00000021-220063 | -220063 |
|  | F003-00000001-196322906 | -196322906 |
|  | F004-00000125-0176218 | -0176218 |
|  | 85373386 |  |
|  | F004-00000064 |  |
|  | F004-00000044 |  |
|  | F003-00000023 |  |
|  | F003-00000023 |  |
|  | F004-00000061 |  |
|  | 0007-0005006 |  |
|  | F003-00000019-8332 | -8332 |
|  | B003-00000002 |  |
|  | F004-00000135-012040 | -012040 |

### I want what is in the test column to be inserted in the number_operation column, and I made this query

select number_operation,communication,
substr(communication,14) as test
from account_payment

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SUBSTRING` along with a regex pattern.  Assuming you want to *select* this new column, use:

```sql
SELECT number_operation, communication,
       SUBSTRING(communication FROM '[^-]+-[^-]+-(.*)') AS test
FROM yourTable;
```

If you instead want to *update* your table, and the new `test` column has already been created, then use:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET test = SUBSTRING(communication FROM '[^-]+-[^-]+-(.*)')
WHERE communication LIKE '%-%-%';
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering, I made the query and it presents me with the following error


SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "account_payment_number_operation"
  Detail: Key (number_operation)=(42290) already exists.

Please helpme!

Comment: There appears to be a unique constraint on `number_operation`.  Check your data, or maybe remove the unique constraint.